# Is this a bug? I can start a bounty on someone's answered question.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[Network Manager or WICD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3109/network-manager-or-wicd)

I am given an option to start a bounty. This is not my question, and it has been answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a somewhat recent change to how the bounty system works. Among other changes, you can now add a bounty to someone else's question. The changes and details are outlined in this blog post:

[**Improvements to Bounty System**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/)

Comment: Cool, makes sense :)